# With python3 function annotation, how do I check type of function as input?

Tags: python, function, annotations, typechecking

I want to use function to check whether an argument passed to a function is a function or not.

I was doing something like:

```
from types import FunctionType
def f(ff: FunctionType):
    # do something
```

It seems wrong, as I can literaly pass anything to f.

How do I check argument passed in is a function or not with annotation?

Comment: Are you looking for general runtime type-hint checking/enforcement? Something like https://github.com/RussBaz/enforce ?

Answer (score 0):

Python on its own does not enforce types whatsoever - what you shown is just type hinting, which can be use by tools like linters to warn you that you're about to do something that may not work correctly.

If you want to assert the type, you have to do it explicitly inside the function body. Or you can use a static type checker, like [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/).